# Azure DevOps deployment agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to know if the same on-prem machine can be used as both a build agent and a deployment agent. Is there any documentation that reference this?

Answer (score 1):

While we typically try to keep our private build and release agents separate, there is nothing stopping you from doing both with one agent.  Just make sure to pick **Agent Pools (read, manage)** and **Deployment group (read, manage)** when generating your PAT for the agent.

If they are separate agents on the same machine, then that will work too.  We are doing that now.